# How can I get a string as dynamic and convert it into a base64

Tags: swift4.1

```
let parameterDictionary = ["action": "create",   "email": emailTextField?.text, "password":  passwordTextField.text] as [String : Any]
var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue(" application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

how can i get a dynamic value to a textfield and convert it into base64 value for password

Comment: Converting a text into a numeric? Do you mean sha256 ?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears you have a `String` value, there are no methods directly on this type to produce base64 encoding. However there are such methods on `Data`, and you can convert a `String` value to an equivalent `Data` value.

Look at `String`'s function `data(using:)` – it will allow you to obtain a `Data` value consisting of the UTF-8 bytes corresponding to a `String` value (this function is documented under `StringProtocol`, which `String` implements). Now look at `Data`'s documentation, search for `base64`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it's Work for me.**

```
func toBase64EncodedString(_ jsonString : String) -> String
{
    let utf8str = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)

    let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options: [])

    return base64Encoded!
}
```